# Migrating device token registration IDs from Urban Airship to Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, urbanairship.com, android-push-notification

From an Urban Airship Offboarding document, I received the following information:

> We are sorry to see you leave, but want to make your transition a smooth one. Here are some things you'll want to take care of: Make an API call to access all of your device tokens and GCM registration ID's. Why? This will provice the ability to transition those tokens and ID's so the devices that have already opted in to Push Notifications on iOS won't be prompted to do so again if the Customer owns App Bundle ID. http://docs.urbanairship.com/api/ua.html#device-listing.

I was able to successfully fetch Android APIDs registered to my application by using GET /api/apids and the information under the "APID Listing" heading at http://docs.urbanairship.com/api/ua.html#device-listing. However, I am not sure how I can use the APIDs in Firebase Cloud Messaging. What I want is to obtain all of my device tokens and Firebase Cloud Messaging registration ID's from Urban Airship, but not values that are unique to Urban Airship. It is my impression that APIDs are unique to Urban Airship in the same way that Channel IDs (obtained in Java with `UAirship.shared().getPushManager().getChannelId()`) are unique to Urban Airship as well. I am trying to export device tokens from Urban Airship so that I can use them from Firebase Cloud Messaing independently from Urban Airship. In other words, I want to migrate devices off of Urban Airship. Is there a way to obtain device tokens in the same format that the `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()` method returns them? That format would look like this:

f32EVa9yfbo:AJA91bFg53ZuQLWYSDDqPlkf4a88Lu6Gp4DoXVDJ2wRIlnjDngq0UdNnlSi7wxbbut6YX7Z1kmvyS3bhk_Zrl-1doHCf5XFdOXTThNzo4sXASWqQjHKfNa3pH2Js4Zlbf_CtRkD2Peho

Thank you.

**UPDATE 1:**

I found a way to obtain a GCM registration ID:

**Step 1. Using `GET /api/apids` to fetch Android APIDs registered to this application, along with associated metadata:**

```
C:\curl>curl -k https://go.urbanairship.com/api/apids/ -u "<AppKey>:<MasterSecret>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET |more
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0{
  "next_page" : "https://go.urbanairship.com/api/apids/?start=0584f193-07a0-49f7-b2d3-92f8e05ur6b5&limit=1000",
  "apids" : [ {
"tags" : [ "City-1" ],
"alias" : null,
"active" : false,
"created" : "2017-07-17 23:02:40",
"apid" : "00027235-66b4-4433-a40f-254532d8abd1"
  }, {
"tags" : [ "City-1" ],
"alias" : null,
"active" : true,
"created" : "2017-09-14 15:41:35",
"apid" : "00036ca3-d628-4353-be92-0dc6fe03afc6"
      }, {
"tags" : [ "city-2" ],
"alias" : null,
"active" : true,
"created" : "2017-09-18 16:38:39",
"apid" : "000222f5-824a-42f2-8ba0-c58b4c2fb2a2"
  }, {
"tags" : [ "city-2" ],
-- More  --
```

The result was a long array that contains many apids

**Step 2. Using `GET /api/apids/(APID)` to get information on a particular Android APID**

```
C:\curl>curl -k https://go.urbanairship.com/api/apids/000222f5-824a-42f2-8ba0-c58b4c2fb2a2 -u "<AppKey>:<MasterSecret>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET
{"last_registration":"2017-12-14 17:36:05","created":"2017-10-19 17:05:18","gcm_registration_id":"bIY0GH6-hqk:APA91bH2xUBtlfga2kBG0GjvjbBYrI3M72BbXc3tTo7pSuY61w1wrgOeTbEqEd5J2SmUcQx25uU8TafWk2tDP7Vf7bc0ZsQrtENlFJDNIb--LUVuZimjOegyaepPYuQvm_9gmJDsviwY","apid":"000222f5-824a-42f2-8ba0-c58b4c2fb2a2","alias":"","active":true,"tags":["city-2"]}
```

Now I see something returned in a format that Firebase Cloud Messaging could recognize as a device token ID, and that I could use to send a push notification from Firebase Cloud Messaging without Urban Airship:

bIY0GH6-hqk:APA91bH2xUBtlfga2kBG0GjvjbBYrI3M72BbXc3tTo7pSuY61w1wrgOeTbEqEd5J2SmUcQx25uU8TafWk2tDP7Vf7bc0ZsQrtENlFJDNIb--LUVuZimjOegyaepPYuQvm_9gmJDsviwY

Now, the complication that I see is that as you can see above, I had to provide a specific APID in order to receive the `gcm_registration_id` for that APID. When I only use `GET /api/apids` as I put an example in Step 1 above, I do not get any `gcm_registration_id` in the returned array. This makes the process of obtaining `gcm_registration_id` values extremely tedious and long, because I would have to be using `GET /api/apids/(APID)` as in the example I wrote in Step 2, for every APID returned by the 
"GET /api/apids" that I wrote in Step 1. If I have for example 70,000 APID values, I would have to be doing this tedious process 70,000 times unless I write a script or some way to automate the process of downloading the APIDs. Is is possible that when I use `GET /api/apids` as in Step 1, that I can immediately receive as part of the arrays in the metadata, `gcm_registration_id` values? That would facilitate the process of dowloading the `gcm_registration_id` values so that I can use them in Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Also, I would like to receive a confirmation if the `gcm_registration_id` values that I see are the device token ID values that I can use in Firebase Cloud Messaging to send push notifications to devices without using Urban Airship.

**UPDATE 2:**

The problem is that I need to use `https://go.urbanairship.com/api/apids/{apid}` in order to see the `gcm_registration_id` values, and I do not want to do that because if I have 70,000 registered devices, I would have to make 70,000 cURL queries providing each of the 70,000 `{apid}` values 70,000 times. It would take forever! If I only use `https://go.urbanairship.com/api/apids/` without `{apid}`, the returned array does not include `gcm_registration_id` values.

**UPDATE 3:**

Is the solution writing Java code with a request to https://go.urbanairship.com/api/apids to obtain and store an array of APID values, and then pass each element of that array as the the `{apid}` to then make a loop of requests to `https://go.urbanairship.com/api/apids/{apid}` in order to obtain all of the GCM/FCM device tokens registered to my app? I guess a single cURL request to https://go.urbanairship.com/api/apids may not be enough to obtain all of the GCM/FCM device tokens registered to my app; and requests, arrays, and loops in Java code may be a must in order to get those tokens I am trying to download. I will appreciate if someone could confirm this.

Comment: Have you tried the channel listing API? That should return any push address registered for a device, not just the Urban Airship identifier.  https://docs.urbanairship.com/api/ua/#channel-list-api

Comment: @gatlinhebert Yes, I have already tried Channel IDs. I went to the "Channel Listing" heading at https://docs.urbanairship.com/api/ua/#channel-list-api and in the example response in that section, you can see how the response does not include any `gcm_registration_id`. Also, I contacted Urban Airship Support to ask about channel IDs, and this is what they said: "Channel IDs are unique to Urban Airship. You can export device tokens from UA though. I've attached our off-boarding document which gives some good guidance on migrating devices off of UA." The off-boarding doc. is a link to the UA API.

Comment: @gatlinhebert I just realized that your comment had already provided the answer that I eventually received from the Urban Airship Support Team. You can put your comment as an answer so that I can choose it as the best answer, even though I answered my own question and provided details that could help someone with the same problem in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I received a reply from Urban Airship Support Center, and they were explaining to me that the GCM/FCM token for Android devices, they call it `push_address`. I went to verify those values and I see they have the format that Firebase Cloud Messaging uses, so I could finally have a way to download the tokens using the Urban Airship API. This is the reply from their tech support:

> [Name of Employee] (Urban Airship Support Center)
>
> Dec 20, 5:10 PM PST
>
> Hi Jaime,
>
> This is [Name of Employee] with Urban Airship Technical Support.
>
> Try using the [`/api/channels` endpoint](https://docs.urbanairship.com/api/ua/#channel-list-api). The `push_address` value
>   should be the GCM/FCM token for Android devices. The response is
>   paginated and contains a next_page value.
>
> If you need any help pulling the data from this endpoint, or it does
>   not contain the data you are looking for, please let me know.
>
> Thank you, 
>   [Name of Employee] 
>   Urban Airship Technical Support
>   Portland, Oregon

I am using the following request for example, and you can see how I get the GCM/FCM device tokens. Note: I randomly changed characters in the tokens, but you can still see the format.

```
C:\curl>curl -k https://go.urbanairship.com/api/channels/ -u "<AppKey>:<MasterSecret>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET |more
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  683k    0  683k    0     0   227k      0 --:--:--  0:00:03 --:--:--  205k
{"ok":true,"channels":[{"channel_id":"00099045-24a4-2523-a80f-876423d8abd2","device_type":"android","installed":false,"background":false,"push_address":"c2XddiCxuLf:APA91bG8-XqUuyZKnf3A0zJI7xFi3_KsOvyS7X9t2fDYpECKhMGcMdcIjggRfFcr0GAnQCDB9qRn9goC1wcVWxT2aapu578v83LlcgsgqvPFC0dZCVNi0CTZyRA4A4B0dQY7aVgWhxh2","named_user_id":null,"alias":null,"tags":["city-1"],"tag_groups":{"timezone":["America/Costa_Rica"],"ua_android_app_version":["1.21"],"ua_locale_country":["US"],"ua_locale_language":["es"],"ua_android_sdk_version":["8.3.X"],"ua_android_version":["5.1.X"],"ua_location_enabled":["false"],"ua_opt_in":["false"],"ua_background_enabled":["false"]},"created":"2017-07-17T23:02:40","opt_in":false,"last_registration":"2017-08-05T02:33:26"},{"channel_id":"00032ba5-d613-4323-be92-0ac6fe04cfd6","device_type":"android","installed":true,"background":true,"push_address":"ceG5aSa0i6o:ERT91bF0UPUvbEzP4UnlwonfyFVc55FcecQkCesXcqhJglY5UlqIAN88VwH7xadEIoWj4FsHZsYu56jiHzUJqozPawXPGNPW71TbVFeFLVNWBkzpqDgt-8Kftj-ce_Z_vpKNIrXvlAwQ","named_user_id":null,"alias":null,"tags":["city-1"],"tag_groups":{"timezone":["America/Chicago"],"ua_android_app_version":["1.21"],"ua_locale_country":["SV"],"ua_locale_language":["es"],"ua_android_sdk_version":["8.3.X"],"ua_android_version":["6.0.X"],"ua_location_enabled":["false"],"ua_opt_in":["true"],"ua_background_enabled":["true"]},"created":"2017-09-14T15:41:35","opt_in":true,"last_registration":"2017-12-20T13:12:09"},.........
```

**UPDATE 1:** Where to find the `<AppKey>:<MasterSecret>` of the code that I am showing above? It is at https://go.urbanairship.com/apps/. Go to the settings page and find it in the areas that I am highlighting with ovals below:

[image]

**UPDATE 2:** If we know the Urban Airship `channel_id`, we can get the `push_address` (what Urban Airship calls `push_address` is the `GCM/FCM device token ID`). For example, imagine that I know that the Urban Airship `channel_id` of my phone is `88cb7c8a-a207-4136-b55f-97d7238df916`. Then I can use the Airship API (https://docs.airship.com/api/ua/) to execute the following cURL command:

```
C:\curl>curl -k https://go.urbanairship.com/api/channels/88cb7c8a-a207-4136-b55f-97d7238df916 -u "<AppKey>:<MasterSecret>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET |more
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   739  100   739    0     0    739      0  0:00:01 --:--:--  0:00:01  1213
{"ok":true,"channel":{"channel_id":"88cb7c8a-a207-4136-b55f-97d7238df916","device_type":"android","installed":true,"background":true,"push_address":"cbDusDAn_zE:APA91bF9su16_w4DD5qE5OgM_4E23FvIQJa84UWtvUz7zcdFf3B9WijdL1v1IaWwQTSg74doE_RMdJiCvYH1hJgWS7ELaujxhdz1SQ24EInef9JKfz3a27PTRYreTG_vMuTYkLa5T7f5","named_user_id":null,"alias":null,"tags":["guatemala-city"],"tag_groups":{"timezone":["America/Chicago"],"ua_android_app_version":["1.24"],"ua_locale_country":["US"],"ua_locale_language":["en"],"ua_android_sdk_version":["8.3.X"],"ua_android_version":["6.0.X"],"ua_location_enabled":["false"],"ua_opt_in":["true"],"ua_background_enabled":["true"]},"created":"2018-12-26T14:56:44","opt_in":true,"last_registration":"2019-05-18T06:55:39"}}

C:\curl>
```

Comment: Were you able to import the users into firebase?

Comment: @SyedSaad It's been a while but if I remember correctly, I did successfully import all contacts.

Comment: I can get only 1000 users and then the pagination does not seem to work, was it the same for you?

Comment: @SyedSaad I don't remember experiencing any pagination issues but maybe the Airship support team can help to double check if that is a glitch. I used `|more` with `curl`.

Comment: Does '|more' sort of hang if there are a lot of users?

Comment: @SyedSaad I don't remember that. Maybe you can give it a try.